# I have a field date_returned of type date, what is the best practice?

Tags: sql, database

I have a field date_returned of type date, what is the best practice, when entering a row it gives '0000-00-00' or is better to set it NULL?

when I insert data onto it, and miss out the field it gives the value:

'0000-00-00'.

This fine for me at the moment, but is it better practice to set to to NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL can help you using WHERE clause here. Any way, business requirement is the first and last thing you care about..

I came across a  similar thread [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583677/is-it-good-practice-to-set-all-database-columns-as-not-null) which appeared very meaningful to me in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to satisfy your business requirements.